# How to save multiple records in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm very new in cakephp 3. I want to save multiple records with multiple checkbox. 
I've some events in events table & some passwords in passwords table.
I want to set different passwords under each events.
For example- For event 1 I want to set some passwords which will be stored in event_password_all table.

> (id, event1, password1),
>   (id, event1, password2),
>   (id, event1, password3),
>   …
>   …
>   (id, event1, passwordN)

How can I do that.

Here is my controller code-

```
    public function add()
{
    $eventPasswordAll = $this->EventPasswordAll->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {       
        $eventPasswordAll = $this->EventPasswordAll->patchEntity($eventPasswordAll, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->EventPasswordAll->save($eventPasswordAll)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The event password all has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The event password all could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $events = $this->EventPasswordAll->Events->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $passwords = $this->EventPasswordAll->Passwords->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('eventPasswordAll', 'events', 'passwords'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['eventPasswordAll']);
}
```

& here is view-

```
<div class="eventPasswordAll form large-10 medium-9 columns">
<?= $this->Form->create($eventPasswordAll) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Event Password All') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('event_id', ['options' => $events]);
        echo $this->Form->input('password_id', ['options' => $passwords, 'multiple' => 'checkbox']);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: I want to add some passwords against an event. In event_password_all table want to save data like (event1, pass1), (event1, pass2), (event1, pass3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Before 3.2.8:**
Theres no such event as saveAll in CakePHP 3. 
You must iterate through your options.

Example:

```
$passwords = $this->request->data('password_id');

foreach ($passwords as $password) {
    $data = [
        'event_id'    => $this->request->data('event_id'),
        'password_id' => $password
    ];
    $eventPasswordAll = $this->EventPasswordAll->newEntity();
    $this->EventPasswordAll->patchEntity($eventPasswordAll, $data);
    $this->EventPasswordAll->save($eventPasswordAll );
}
```

I did not test it, but you get the idea

**>= 3.2.8**
To keep ppl on the right track.
As of 3.2.8 there's a way to do this more efficient.
Cookbook: [saving-multiple-entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities)

```
$data = [
    [
        'title' => 'First post',
        'published' => 1
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Second post',
        'published' => 1
    ],
];
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$entities = $articles->newEntities($data);
$result = $articles->saveMany($entities);
```

Comment: its bad practice to use query in loops

Comment: Yes but this was the only way before 3.2.8 -> Correct way with newer Versions see Puneet's Post

Comment: @PascalRuscher its not working in cakephp-3.2.7. Its giving an error `Unknown method "saveMany"`. Any alternative to SaveMany ?

Comment: @Rakesh You need to iterate and save one by one. Before 3.2.8 there’s no other option

Answer (score 4):

From CakePHP version 3.2.8 you can save multiple records at once. You can use below code as mentioned on the cakephp documents.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities

```
$data = [
 [
    'title' => 'First post',
    'published' => 1
 ],
 [
    'title' => 'Second post',
    'published' => 1
 ],
];
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$entities = $articles->newEntities($data);
$result = $articles->saveMany($entities);
```

Comment: i am also trying to add multiple records. But i am unable to save the data. Because i am getting different post array  data. Anyone can help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @puneet Any alternative of saveMany in cakephp-3.2.7 ?