# CakePHP 3.7.7 saving multiple entities efficiently

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

CakePHP 3.7.7

I have a series of checkboxes. Name attributes are: `emailFrequency_daily`, `emailFrequency_weekly` and `emailFrequency_monthly`.

I want to save the ones that have been checked and need to save these alongside some other data I have stored in the session: session data `o_id` and `u_id` are the same every time a row is inserted. A `frequency` field in the database matches the appropriate checkbox and is different every time as per the list above.

So I have tried following https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities

In my Controller I have the following

```
$TblAlertFrequency = TableRegistry::get('TblAlertFrequency');

$frequencies = [];

// 'daily' emails enabled
if ($this->request->getData('emailFrequency_daily')) {
    $frequencies[] = [
        'u_id' => $this->_UserModel->getUserId(),
        'o_id' => $this->_UserModel->getOrgId(),
        'frequency' => 'daily'
    ];
}

// 'weekly' emails enabled
if ($this->request->getData('emailFrequency_weekly')) {
    $frequencies[] = [
        'u_id' => $this->_UserModel->getUserId(),
        'o_id' => $this->_UserModel->getOrgId(),
        'frequency' => 'weekly'
    ];
}

// 'monthly' emails enabled
if ($this->request->getData('emailFrequency_monthly')) {
    $frequencies[] = [
        'u_id' => $this->_UserModel->getUserId(),
        'o_id' => $this->_UserModel->getOrgId(),
        'frequency' => 'monthly'
    ];
}

if (!empty($frequencies)) {
    $entities = $TblAlertFrequency->newEntities($frequencies);
    $TblAlertFrequency->saveMany($entities);
}
```

It's giving a 500 Internal Server error with the message:

> Error: Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got (, ), expecting (o_id, u_id)

Why is this, given I'm passing it those values (`o_id` and `u_id`)?

The table structure is as follows:

```
    mysql> describe tbl_alert_frequency;
    +-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field     | Type                                     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | u_id      | mediumint(8) unsigned                    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | o_id      | smallint(5) unsigned                     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | frequency | enum('never','daily','weekly','monthly') | NO   |     | weekly  |       |
    +-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The only thing I'm not passing it is the `id` because that's `AUTO_INCREMENT` and therefore written by MySQL on inserting a new row.

The code I've written here isn't DRY because it repeats:

```
'u_id' => $this->_UserModel->getUserId(),
'o_id' => $this->_UserModel->getOrgId(),
```

But if I remove those it won't save them, and they are needed on every row.

Surely there is an easier and more efficient way to write this?

I also looked at [How to save multiple records in cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691451/how-to-save-multiple-records-in-cakephp-3) but that seems outdated and didn't work for me.

Comment: According to that error CakePHP thinks that you have a compound primary key that consists of the fields `u_id` and `o_id`. Have you changed that lately and added the `id` column as a primary key? If so make sure to clear your model cache (`tmp/cache/models`), and ensure that the table class defines the `id` column as the primary key in its `initialize()` method.

Comment: @ndm thanks. Originally `u_id` and `o_id` were primary keys. So I added the `id` field and set that to be primary, as I thought that was the source of the error. I've reverted the table back but it's still giving the same error; I will try clearing the cache as you've suggested. Incidentally is the way I've written this code as DRY as possible? I'm aware I've repeated those statements to add `u_id` and `o_id` which doesn't seem great?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the table structure now. So it's the same but I've removed the `id` field and reverted the keys back to `u_id` and `o_id`. Cleared the cache data but it's still giving a 500 error with the same message

Comment: The problem seems to be that in the Entity class (`Model/Entity/TblAlertFrequency.php`) it had inside `protected $_accessible` the array keys `u` and `o`. These came from Bake, and I'm not sure why. I edited them to `u_id` and `o_id` respectively, cleared the cache and now it's working